# Mysql, escaped string fields couldn't be searched with "LIKE" keyword

Tags: php, mysql

Consider one of the field( sample_field ) in Mysql table has as "your\'s data", when I query the same table as

`SELECT * FROM sample_table WHERE sample_field = "your\'s data"`

and also like as

`SELECT * FROM sample_table WHERE sample_field = "your's data"`

both of the above query returns 0 rows, even though the `sample_field` has the value as "your\'s data"

After a long search I came to know that, my search would be

`SELECT * FROM sample_table WHERE sample_field = "your\\\'s data"`

that is working very fine. but

`SELECT * FROM sample_table WHERE sample_field LIKE "your\\\'s data"`

is not working. So if I want to search any product or categories with quotes( like "your's data" ), in site search I must use `LIKE` keyword with wildcard patterns('%').

Now I have found the answer that if I try like this

`SELECT * FROM sample_table WHERE sample_field LIKE "your\\\\'s data"`

as given in http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like, it is working fine.

But please let me know why it needs this amount of 4 back slashes to achieve this ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sidenote, I think there shouldn't be a backslash in the database...

Comment: Why do you have a backslash in your database to begin with? That's what I call garbage data.

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to escape the escaping backslash, if you want it to be a literal backslash:

```
WHERE sample_field = "your\\'s data"
```

But really, having a backslash in your database in the first place is the mistake, fix that instead.

Comment: +1 for probably-a-mistake, typically a sign of incorrect input handling such as magic quotes. PS. use single quotes for string literals in preference as double quotes have a different meaning in ANSI SQL.

Comment: True for the single quotes, in which case you'll need a triple-backslash to escape the apostrophe. :)

Comment: Dear deceze, `WHERE sample_field = "your\\'s data"`, is not working there you need to give as `WHERE sample_field = "your\\\'s data"`. but `WHERE sample_field LIKE "%your\\\'s data%"` is not working fine

Answer (score 1):

Because MySQL uses C escape syntax in strings (for example, “\n” to represent a newline character), you must double any “\” that you use in LIKE strings. For example, to search for “\n”, specify it as “\n”. To search for “\”, specify it as “\\”; this is because the backslashes are stripped once by the parser and again when the pattern match is made, leaving a single backslash to be matched against.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
... WHERE sample_field = 'your\'s data'
```